# Glitch in 3D surface plot using pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I want to plot a surface plot in two parameters with pgfplots. A part of the surface which should appear behind the main surface as above it, which looks like a glitch.
[image: Plot with glitch.]
If I reverse the y axis, everything looks fine:
[image: Plot with reversed y axis and no glitch.]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}%[y dir=reverse]
  \addplot3[surf,mesh/ordering=y varies]
    table {glitch.dat};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Glitch.dat can be found here: http://pastebin.com/bEyyKSnz
Is there a parameter to pass to pgfplots to avoid this?

Comment: You could check into the various possible settings of the `z buffer` key, described in Section 4.6.5 of the `pgfplots` manual.

Comment: Adding 'z buffer=sort' solved the problem! Thanks! Can you turn your comment into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For 3-dimensional plots, `pgfplots` uses `z buffer=auto` to try to determine the smartest way to paint the drawing with the correct patches on top. In this case, the `auto` method doesn't produce acceptable results.

Use `z buffer=sort` to correct the issue. The possibilities for `z buffer` are described in Section 4.6.5 of the current (v1.11) [`pgfplots` manual](http://www.texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}%[y dir=reverse]
  \addplot3[surf,mesh/ordering=y varies,z buffer=sort]
    table {glitch.dat};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]