# Glitch in 3D surface plot using pgfplots not solved by z buffer

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

The solution from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204828/glitch-in-3d-surface-plot-using-pgfplots) does not work for me.

The function is (x+y)^A. If I plot it with A larger than one, the 3D graph is fine. However, the graph is horrible if A is lower than one. According to Wolfram, for A=0.5 the graph should be [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+z%3D%28y-x%29%5E0.5). Yet, I get:

[image: Plot]

The code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb,color,pgfplots,tikz}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\PHI{0.5}
        \begin{axis}[xlabel=$i_{1}$,ylabel=$i_{2}$,zlabel=$Y$,grid=major,view={45}{45}]
            \addplot3[surf,domain=0:1,samples=19,z buffer=sort]
            { (y-x)^0.5};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `unbounded coords=jump` in the `addplot3` options.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb,color,pgfplots,tikz}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\PHI{0.5}
        \begin{axis}[xlabel=$i_{1}$,ylabel=$i_{2}$,zlabel=$Y$,grid=major,view={45}{45}]
            \addplot3[surf,unbounded coords=jump,domain=0:1,samples=19,z buffer=sort]
            { (y-x)^0.5};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! I was looking through the pgfplot doc for a magic command but could not find it. This solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis! I'll consider modifications of the default configuration of `pgfplots` such that it will solve this out of the box in the future.